# Access VBA: set ComboBox height through function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to use a function to adjust the `height` of a `ComboBox`. This is the simplified code :

```
Private Sub Form_ComboBox_AfterUpdate()
    Adjust_Box (Me.Data_Subject_Categories)
End Sub

Private Function Adjust_Box(ctl)
    ctl.Height = 300
End Function
```

But I get the error:

> Run-time error '424': Object required

on this row :

```
ctl.Height = 300
```

How can I fix it? thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You are using parentheses where you shouldn't, causing evaluation of the parameter - it passes the *value* of `Me.Data_Subject_Categories`, not the object.

Use

```
Call Adjust_Box(Me.Data_Subject_Categories)
```

or

```
Adjust_Box Me.Data_Subject_Categories
```